# COALESCE... Can anybody help me to optimize this code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

Can anybody help me to optimize this code? At present it takes 17 seconds.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--SpResumeSearch NULL,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,NULL,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,10,NULL

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpResumeSearch] 
    @Keyword varchar(50) = NULL,
    @JobCategoryId int  = NULL,
    @NationalityId int = NULL,
    @CountryId int = NULL,
    @LocationId int = NULL,
    @Email nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @Gender int = NULL,
    @PassportNumber nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @VisaStatus int = NULL,
    @PoBox nvarchar(10) = NULL,
    @CareerLevelId int = NULL,
    @KeySkills nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @ExpectedSalary int = NULL,
    @Experience int = NULL,
    @DOB varchar(20) = NULL,
    @AppliedFrom datetime = NULL,
    @AppliedTo datetime = NULL,
    @MaritalStatusId int = NULL,
    @LanguageId int = NULL,
    @PageIndex int,
    @NumRows int, 
    @SortCol varchar(20) = NULL 
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @startRowIndex INT;
    SET @startRowIndex = (@PageIndex * @NumRows) + 1;

    WITH ResumeListTemp AS 
        (SELECT DISTINCT M.MemberID, R.ResumeID, R.CreatedDate, R.ModifiedDate, R.CompletedDate, RP.FirstName, RP.LastName, G.Title AS Gender, 
        RP.DateOfBirth, C.NationalityTitle AS Nationality, RPD.KeySkills, RPD.ExperienceYear AS Experience, V.Title AS VisaStatus, RC.Phone, RC.Mobile, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN @SortCol='FIRSTNAME' THEN FirstName END, 
            CASE WHEN @SortCol='LASTNAME' THEN RP.LastName END, 
            CASE WHEN @SortCol='GENDER' THEN G.Title END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='DOB' THEN RP.DateOfBirth END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='NATIONALITY' THEN C.NationalityTitle END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='KEYSKILLS' THEN RPD.KeySkills END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='EXPERIENCE' THEN RPD.ExperienceYear END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='VISASTATUS' THEN V.Title END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='CONTACTNO' THEN RC.Mobile END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='UPDATEDATE' THEN R.ModifiedDate END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol IS NULL THEN R.CompletedDate END
        ) AS RowNum
    FROM TblResume AS R

    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumeContactInfo AS RC ON RC.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumePersonalDetail AS RP ON RP.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumeJobCategory AS RJC ON RJC.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumeProfessionalDetail AS RPD ON RPD.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumeWorkExperience AS RE ON RE.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumeEducation AS RQ ON RQ.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumeSkill AS RS ON RS.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblMember AS M ON M.MemberID = R.FKMemberID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblMasterGender AS G ON G.GenderID = RP.FKGenderID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblMasterCountry AS C ON C.CountryID = RP.FKNationalityID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblRisVisaStatus AS V ON V.VisaStatusID = RP.FKVisaStatusID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblResumeLanguage AS L ON L.FKResumeID = R.ResumeID

    WHERE (
--      RC.Address LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword,RC.Address)+'%' OR
--      RC.City LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword,RC.City)+'%' OR
        R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _RQ.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeEducation AS _RQ, TblResume AS _R WHERE _RQ.Specialization LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword, _RQ.Specialization)+'%' AND _RQ.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _RQ.FKResumeID) OR
        R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _RQ.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeEducation AS _RQ, TblResume AS _R WHERE _RQ.Institution LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword, _RQ.Institution)+'%' AND _RQ.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _RQ.FKResumeID) OR
        RP.FirstName LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword,RP.FirstName)+'%' OR
        RP.LastName LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword,RP.LastName)+'%' OR
        --RP.PassportNumber LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword,RP.PassportNumber)+'%' OR
        --(@Keyword IS NULL OR RP.PassportNumber LIKE '%' + @Keyword +'%') OR
        RPD.Summary LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword,RPD.Summary)+'%' OR
--      R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _RS.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeSkill AS _RS, TblResume AS _R WHERE _RS.Title LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword,_RS.Title)+'%' AND _RS.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _RS.FKResumeID) OR
--      R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _RE.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeWorkExperience AS _RE, TblResume AS _R WHERE _RE.Employer LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword, _RE.Employer)+'%' AND _RE.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _RE.FKResumeID) OR
        R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _RE.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeWorkExperience AS _RE, TblResume AS _R WHERE _RE.Designation LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword, _RE.Designation)+'%' AND _RE.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _RE.FKResumeID) OR
        R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _RE.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeWorkExperience AS _RE, TblResume AS _R WHERE _RE.Responsibilities LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Keyword, _RE.Responsibilities)+'%' AND _RE.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _RE.FKResumeID)) AND 
        R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _RJC.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeJobCategory AS _RJC, TblResume AS _R WHERE _RJC.FKJobCategoryID = COALESCE(@JobCategoryId, _RJC.FKJobCategoryID) AND _RJC.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _RJC.FKResumeID ) AND
        RP.FKNationalityID = COALESCE(@NationalityId, RP.FKNationalityID) AND
        RC.FKCountryID = COALESCE(@CountryId, RC.FKCountryID) AND
--      RPD.FKJobLocationID = COALESCE(@LocationId, RPD.FKJobLocationID) AND 
--      M.Email LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@Email, M.Email)+'%' AND  
--      RP.FKGenderID = COALESCE(@Gender, RP.FKGenderID) AND  
--      RP.PassportNumber LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@PassportNumber, RP.PassportNumber)+'%' AND    
--      RP.FKVisaStatusID = COALESCE(@VisaStatus, RP.FKVisaStatusID) AND    
--      COALESCE(RC.ZipCode,'0') LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@PoBox, COALESCE(RC.ZipCode,'0'))+'%' AND 
        RPD.FKExperienceLevelID = COALESCE(@CareerLevelId, RPD.FKExperienceLevelID) AND 
--      RPD.KeySkills LIKE '%'+COALESCE(@KeySkills, RPD.KeySkills)+'%' AND 
        RPD.FKSalaryID = COALESCE(@ExpectedSalary, RPD.FKSalaryID) AND  
        RPD.ExperienceYear = COALESCE(@Experience, RPD.ExperienceYear) AND  
        RP.DateOfBirth = COALESCE(@DOB, RP.DateOfBirth) AND 
        R.CompletedDate = COALESCE(@AppliedFrom, R.CompletedDate) AND
        R.CompletedDate = COALESCE(@AppliedTo, R.CompletedDate) AND 
        RP.FKMaritalStatusID = COALESCE(@MaritalStatusId, RP.FKMaritalStatusID) AND 
        R.ResumeID IN ( SELECT _L.FKResumeID FROM TblResumeLanguage AS _L, TblResume AS _R WHERE _L.FKLanguageID = COALESCE(@LanguageId, _L.FKLanguageID) AND _L.FKResumeID=_R.ResumeID GROUP BY _L.FKResumeID ) AND
        R.IsCompleted = 1
    )

    SELECT ResumeListTemp.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) from ResumeListTemp) AS RecCount 
        FROM ResumeListTemp
        WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND @StartRowIndex + @NumRows - 1
        ORDER BY             
            CASE WHEN @SortCol='FIRSTNAME' THEN FirstName END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='LASTNAME' THEN LastName END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='GENDER' THEN Gender END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='DOB' THEN DateOfBirth END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='NATIONALITY' THEN Nationality END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='KEYSKILLS' THEN KeySkills END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='EXPERIENCE' THEN Experience END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='VISASTATUS' THEN VisaStatus END, 
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='CONTACTNO' THEN Mobile END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol='UPDATEDATE' THEN ModifiedDate END,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol IS NULL THEN CompletedDate END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

try to replace * with the column names

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think that building your query dynamically and using [`sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) will give you much better performance.

There's an MSDN article explaining the basics [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx), and there are some more in-depth articles by Erland Sommarskog, [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) and [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html).

Answer (score 0):

Having '%' at the very start of a LIKE clause can cause a table scan, try to remove them if possible.

Answer (score 0):

since there is only one column to be sorted in the result, you may try to replace the ORDER BY clause (twice!) as

```
CASE @SortCol 
    WHEN 'FIRSTNAME' THEN FirstName 
    WHEN 'LASTNAME' THEN LastName 
    etc
    ELSE CompletedDate 
END
```

(you probably need to CONVERT columns to NVARCHAR)

Answer (score 0):

Optimization for WHERE section - seems to me, there is no need of using IN clause, thouse tables are already joined by ResumeID, all you need is to filter them out:

```
    WHERE (
(RQ.Specialization IS NOT NULL AND (@Keyword IS NULL OR RQ.Specialization LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%')) OR
(RQ.Institution IS NOT NULL AND (@Keyword IS NULL OR RQ.Institution LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%')) OR
(RP.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND (@Keyword IS NULL OR RP.FirstName LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%')) OR
(RP.LastName IS NOT NULL AND (@Keyword IS NULL OR RP.LastName LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%')) OR
(RPD.Summary IS NOT NULL AND (@Keyword IS NULL OR RPD.Summary LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%')) OR
(RE.Designation IS NOT NULL AND (@Keyword IS NULL OR RE.Designation LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%')) OR
(RE.Responsibilities IS NOT NULL AND (@Keyword IS NULL OR RE.Responsibilities LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%'))) AND 
(RJC.FKJobCategoryID IS NOT NULL AND (@JobCategoryId IS NULL OR RE.Designation LIKE '%'+@JobCategoryId+'%')) AND
RP.FKNationalityID = COALESCE(@NationalityId, RP.FKNationalityID) AND 
RC.FKCountryID = COALESCE(@CountryId, RC.FKCountryID) AND
RPD.FKExperienceLevelID = COALESCE(@CareerLevelId, RPD.FKExperienceLevelID) AND 
RPD.FKSalaryID = COALESCE(@ExpectedSalary, RPD.FKSalaryID) AND  
RPD.ExperienceYear = COALESCE(@Experience, RPD.ExperienceYear) AND  
RP.DateOfBirth = COALESCE(@DOB, RP.DateOfBirth) AND 
R.CompletedDate = COALESCE(@AppliedFrom, R.CompletedDate) AND
R.CompletedDate = COALESCE(@AppliedTo, R.CompletedDate) AND 
RP.FKMaritalStatusID = COALESCE(@MaritalStatusId, RP.FKMaritalStatusID) AND 
(L.FKLanguageID IS NOT NULL AND (@LanguageId IS NULL OR L.FKLanguageID LIKE '%'+@LanguageId+'%')) AND
R.IsCompleted = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you starting each where clause with a wildcard? you can never optimize using that technique (even if you convert to dynamic SQL) as the database is not unable to use the indexes. Require your users to to at a minimum put in the first letter of what they are searching for.

Get rid of the subselects, they are performance killers. Since you are already joining to those tables, you shouldn't need them.